# SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Unexpected token o

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

I have a Node.js Heroku app on Facebook, and I keep on finding the following error in the logs (while getting a generic Application Error when I actually try to access my app):

```
2013-03-27T12:58:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web
.js`
2013-03-27T12:58:55+00:00 app[web.1]: info: socket.io started
2013-03-27T12:58:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 6925
2013-03-27T12:58:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined:1
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Failed to parse JSON body: Un
expected token o
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.parse (native)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)

2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.mixin._fireError (/app
/node_modules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:192:10)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.parsers.json (/app/
node_modules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:367:9)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.FaceplateSession.get (
/app/node_modules/faceplate/index.js:121:25)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at mixin._responseHandler (/app/node_m
odules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:142:20)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.mixin._encode (/app/no
de_modules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:184:29)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at IncomingMessage.parsers.auto (/app/
node_modules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:356:21)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at mixin._responseHandler (/app/node_m
odules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:140:16)
2013-03-27T13:00:40+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.mixin._decode (/app/no
de_modules/faceplate/node_modules/restler/lib/restler.js:156:7)
2013-03-27T13:00:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-03-27T13:00:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

In my server code, I am using `JSON.stringify`, e.g. `console.log(data + ': is in the tags table, with tag_id=' + JSON.stringify(result));` where `result` is the answer returned from a query to a Postgres database. However, I never use `JSON.parse`, so this bug is a tad confusing, also I have never had this bug until today (my app was working fine on Monday).

What is also confusing is that if I comment out the `JSON.stringify` calls I still get the error, so any ideas would be very much appreciated!

As per https://github.com/heroku/faceplate/issues/26, I have made the following changes to my code:

```
function handle_facebook_request(req, res) {

  // if the user is logged in
  if (req.facebook.token) {

 async.parallel([
  function(cb) {
    // query 4 friends and send them to the socket for this socket id
    req.facebook.get('/me/friends', { limit: 4 }, function(friends) {
      req.friends = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(friends));
      cb();
    });
  },
  function(cb) {
    // query 16 photos and send them to the socket for this socket id
    req.facebook.get('/me/photos', { limit: 16 }, function(photos) {
      req.photos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(photos));
      cb();
    });
  },
  function(cb) {
    // query 4 likes and send them to the socket for this socket id
    req.facebook.get('/me/likes', { limit: 4 }, function(likes) {
      req.likes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(likes));
      cb();
    });
  },
  function(cb) {
    // use fql to get a list of my friends that are using this app
    req.facebook.fql('SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user = 1', function(result) {
      req.friends_using_app = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      cb();
    });
  }
], function() {
  render_page(req, res);
});

  } else {
    render_page(req, res);
  }
}
```

Each line with the `req.????` e.g. `req.friends` used to be just like `req.friends = friends;` i.e. I added both `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` calls, and nothing has changed.

Comment: can you post the string result

Comment: it could be due to bug in restler see here https://github.com/heroku/faceplate/issues/26

Comment: @user568109, `client.query('SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_text = \'' + data + '\';', function(err, result) {` is the line where we get result. The example I gave in my question was just one of the many times I use `JSON.stringify()`, and I have not had issues before. As for what result actually is, it isn't a string, I use `JSON.stringify()` as per the example [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-nodejs). Also, I'm not using restler.

Comment: I get the same error while my app was working a week ago. BTW faceplate is using restler, and you're using faceplate.

Comment: @YiHuang, yeah I just realised that my app was using restler... it's interesting that yours is producing the same error, is yours a Node.js app too? I've got into contact with someone at Heroku so if I hear anything I'll post it here.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Node.js, and I got my app working using the solution provided in the link that was posted by @user568109. (https://github.com/heroku/faceplate/issues/26#issuecomment-15564948)

Comment: Thanks for looking out, OP didnt look at the bug I had posted else it would have been clear, the link itself says its a faceplate bug report. Anyways I will post it as an answer so that others can benefit.

Comment: @YiHuang, where did you make the change suggested on that link; the poster said they made the change where they put arrows <<<<<<<<<<, but I don't currently have a block of code that looks like theirs... The only place in my code (in `web.js` where `cb` is referred to begins like this `function handle_facebook_request(req, res) {

  // if the user is logged in
  if (req.facebook.token) {

  async.parallel([
      function(cb) {` And I know that code was from the original app set up by Facebook by default

Comment: @user568109, I did see the bug but originally thought it was irrelevant, but now realise it is relevant, thank you for posting it :-)

Comment: @YiHuang, I tried this
`req.facebook.get('/me/friends', { limit: 4 }, function(friends) {
          req.friends = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(friends));
          cb();
        });`
everywhere I could see `get` or `fql` calls, but it hasn't worked (bearing in mind that it was previously `req.friends = friends;` and yet it hasn't worked.

Comment: @YiHuang, I've edited my question so what I was trying to say above is a bit clearer.

Comment: @user1562347 The two lines I've modified is in "node_modules/faceplate/index.js" that will look like `var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` after modification. I think modifying the library code should be a temporary solution. Anyway, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned, the solution can be found here: https://github.com/heroku/faceplate/issues/26 It should be noted though that there are now more details on fixing it for ver 0.0.4 of faceplate (thanks to my prompting!)